# Atrributes of django model instance don't change after save()

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.company.name = request.POST['company_name']
    self.company.certification = request.POST['company_pic_url']
    self.company.save()
    return http.HttpResponseRedirect('/company')
```

Here, company is a model instance,name and certification don't change after save()

However

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    company = self.company
    company.name = request.POST['company_name']
    company.certification = request.POST['company_pic_url']
    company.save()
    return http.HttpResponseRedirect('/company')
```

It works well
Someone can explain this? thanks

Comment: How is `self.company` defined? If it is a normal Django model instance, there is no reason the two snippets should have different outcomes.

Comment: `self.company = Company.objects.get(id=1)`
 Company is a normal Django model  as well

Comment: You make sure your post invoked?

Comment: Are you sure you actually _commit_ the transaction after the view has been rendered?

Comment: @kroolik yep，above two have same transaction control

Comment: Do you experience the issue locally, or when deployed? Could be possible that both views are rendered in different workers, and model instances are not _bound_ to the DB object. You could debug it by checking the `id(self.company)` value for both views (those that update, and those that not).

Comment: Where do you actually set `self.company = Company.objects.get(id=1)` in your code? If, for example, `self.company` was a property, the code won't work since it would be re-fetched every time you do `self.company`.